# Can't find the error in my cpp or header file, class construction failing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

Firstly, I am very new to C++ and have had only minimal teaching/practice, so please bear this in mind. I have created a Date class for a project I am working on. I had previously organised my code in a sloppy way, but it had functioned enough for me to write the syntax of my code effectively. After someone looked at my code I realised I needed to structure my classes better, so tried to organise my Date class into a header and cpp file. Having done so, I get a number of errors along the lines of:

> `'day': undeclared identifier`
>   `missing type specifier - int is assumed`

Also, the Date is recognised as a type in the cpp file as it changes colour in Visual Studio, but in the header file the class is not coloured as a type.

A tutor looked through and couldn't help as to where my error was coming from, but if I remove these two files my code functions without errors so it's definitely somewhere in the scripts below. A

I've already tried rebuilding my entire project from scratch as I initially thought it was a directory problem, but having meticulously done this and making thoroughly sure I haven't misplaced a file, I can't see how it would be because of this.

**Date.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date
{
public:
    Date(int y, int m, int d);

    Date();

    const int monthDays[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    int yearsDifference();

    int daysDifference();

    int totalDays();

private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

};

#endif
```

**Date.cpp**

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <Date.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



Date::Date(int y, int m, int d)
{
    y = year;
    m = month;
    d = day;
}

Date::Date()
{
    year = 0;
    month = 0;
    day = 0;
}

static Date today() {
    struct tm ti;
    time_t t = time(0);
    localtime_s(&ti, &t);
    int y = 1900 + ti.tm_year;
    int m = 1 + ti.tm_mon;
    int d = ti.tm_mday;
    return Date(y, m, d);
}



int Date::yearsDifference()
{

    bool laterInYear = (month > today().month)
        || (month == today().month && day > today().day);

    int result = year - today().year;
    if (!laterInYear)
    {
        result--;
    }
    return result;
}



int Date::daysDifference()
{

    int todayMonthDays = 0;
    int maturityMonthDays = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (month - 1); i++) {
        maturityMonthDays += monthDays[i];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < (today().month - 1); i++) {
        todayMonthDays += monthDays[i];
    }

    maturityMonthDays += day;
    todayMonthDays += today().day;

    bool laterInYear = (month > today().month)
        || (month == today().month && day > today().day);

    int result;
    if (laterInYear)
    {
        result = maturityMonthDays - todayMonthDays;
    }
    else
    {
        result = 365 - (todayMonthDays - maturityMonthDays);
    }
    return result;
}

int Date::totalDays()
{
    int result = (yearsDifference() * 365)
        + daysDifference();
    return result;
}

#endif
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been staring at this for hours trying to fix it and I just can't see it.

Comment: You don't need the `#ifdef` stuff in in cpp file.

Comment: Oh my that's fixed it! Thanks so much, what a dumb error! Much appreciated.

Comment: Also be careful with the today() function. It is **not** a static method but instead it is a static function that is only usable in Date.cpp

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `#ifdef` guard in the .cpp file.

That is because `#include` works by copy-n-pasting the entire header file. And because you define DATE_H before you include the Date.h header, DATE_H is also defined in Date.h (which then effectively disables the enitre header).

Answer (score 0):

The Data class constructor should be like this

```
Date::Date(int y, int m, int d):
    year(y),
    month(m),
    day(d)
{}
```

Also remove #ifdef's in the cpp files